Math major looking to learn some CS
I'm currently in school doing a pure math major, and I want to learn some computer science (potentially for jobs in finance requiring it but also just because I think it will be useful for the future), but I'm really unsure where to start, and am just overwhelmed. It seems like my peers majoring in math all have a solid computer science background, while I have none. So, what is a reasonable path to becoming a proficient coder? Which languages should I start with? What seems like the most useful languages for a math major to learn, and are there any good courses, books, etc...? What should my weekly time commitment look like?
I know these are a lot of questions, but thanks in advance!

Does this answer your question? Transitioning from mathematics to computer science

@codeR somewhat? but this person seems to have a good background in computer science despite not being able to take university courses in it. I feel like I'm much more of a beginner am more wondering what the best entry point is for someone who may want to go into quant finance in the future, and what the best path would be. Thanks for answering btw!

If you like textbooks then I can recommend 1 , 2 and 3 as an introduction.
sicp might be especially well suited for a mathematician, and there's a free pdf available for "Programming from the Ground Up".
"The Elements of Computing Systems" also has a website with a lot of free material.

1. Becoming a proficient coder
It's about exposure at the end of the day, my compsci courses started with high readability languages like python. Set yourself up with some projects like re-creating algorithms or basic terminal scripts. I found it "fun" to create a Jupyter notebook (which you can do in VS Code or pyCharm) and make microeconomic functions. Once you've grasped the concepts of a basic language you can progress to a more syntactically difficult one.
2. Which languages should I start with?
I would recommend to start with a language that has high readability to dip your toes in with. Python can be used in statistics, data analysis, machine learning, web scraping, and so much more. At the end of the day it's more about concepts then the actual languages in compsci because you can learn the new hottest language but it won't mean much if you don't know how to produce basic concepts like data structures.
3. What seems like the most useful languages for a math major to learn
Haskell, Matlab, and you might have experience with this already but a good markup language to keep in your back pocket is TeX for programs like Latex. I know they taught me TeX in my discrete mathematics courses. (Think I've forgot quite a bit of it though)
4. What should my weekly time commitment look like
That depends on your opportunity cost of learning it. Is there something else more relevant to learn for what you want your career to be? How serious are you to integrating compsci into your mathematics career? You could  start with an hour a week which might take you a while but if you feel likes it not clicking and you have more time on your hands then expected bump it up until you have a good study flow going. I'd recommend maybe 5 hours a week for a good begining stride.
I hope this was helpful and someone else might have more clarity but I hope you find great success in your future courses and career!
